# tornado Websocket Server: How to create a new object for sending on_message to this object?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I actually try to send a received message (over tornado websocket) to a specific object.

My code looks like this:

```
clients = dict()

class WebServer(object):
    def __init__(self, port=8080):

        define("port", default=port, help="Run on the given port", type=int)

        app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', IndexHandler),
        (r'/(?P<Id>\w*)', MyWebSocketHandler),
        (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path':'static/'}),
        #(r'/ws', MyWebSocketHandler),
        ])

        print("DSP Control Application | Browse to <IP>:"+str(port)+" and have fun!")

        parse_command_line()
        app.listen(options.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        if "Id" in kwargs.keys():
            print "Your client id is: %s" % (kwargs["Id"],)
        self.render("index.html")
        #self.finish()


class MyWebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs["Id"]
        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)
        clients[self.id] = {"id": self.id, "object": self}

    def on_message(self, message):
        print "Client %s received a message: %s" % (self.id, message)
        #self.write_message("Client id: %s" % (list,))


    def on_close(self):
        if self.id in clients:
            del clients[self.id]

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":

    server = WebServer()
```

It's mainly the basic tornado websocket application which already works. The on_message function prints me a message to the console everytime a client connects to my server. So far so good...

But now I want to instantiate a new object from my control class. The on_message function should give the received message to this object.

I'm instantiating the object like this:

```
class WebServer(object):
    def __init__(self, port=8080):

        define("port", default=port, help="Run on the given port", type=int)

        # Instantiate a new Object from class "Control"
        mycontrol = Control()

        app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', IndexHandler),
        (r'/(?P<Id>\w*)', MyWebSocketHandler),
        (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path':'static/'}),
        #(r'/ws', MyWebSocketHandler),
        ])

        ...
```

But how to tell MyWebSocketHandler() that he needs to call mycontrol when he received a message. I found no way to hand over this object to the app object.

Can you please help me with this?

Regards
Borsty

Answer (score 0):

You can pass default kwargs to your `MyWebSocketHandler` at application creation step,
kwargs will be passed to `initialize` method of your handler http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable//web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize

```
class WebServer(object):
    def __init__(self, port=8080):

        define("port", default=port, help="Run on the given port", type=int)

        mycontrol = Control()
        app = tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/', IndexHandler),
            (r'/(?P<Id>\w*)', MyWebSocketHandler, {'control': mycontrol}),
            (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,{'path':'static/'}),
        ])
```

You can store reference to your control instance and use it later

```
class MyWebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self, control):
        self.control = control

    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs["Id"]
        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)
        clients[self.id] = {"id": self.id, "object": self}

    def on_message(self, message):
        print "Client %s received a message: %s" % (self.id, message)
        self.control.send(message)
```